# Efficient Online Algorithms for Matrix rank

Tags: matrices, online-algorithms

Suppose, we have a matrix with known rank. Then, in each step one element of this matrix will be changed. Is there any efficient online algorithm to find rank of each matrix after each element update?

Comment: see https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1283397 and https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0304397509004046/1-s2.0-S0304397509004046-main.pdf?_tid=cef10d30-d3f9-11e7-9958-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1511845733_8aa1eec21588900d583f09a3a59d1350